# Is it possible to iterate method object inside the for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, iteration

I would like to know why using for loop is not displaying a method when iterating the object.

Please check below example where method `getFullList` is not listed:

```js
let list = {
  firstElement: "Element 1",
  secondElement: "Element 2",
  thirdElement: "Element 3",
  getFullList: function() {
    return this.firstElement + ', ' + this.secondElement + ', ' + this.thirdElement;
  }
};

for (let key in list) {
  if (list.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log(key + ' ' + list[key])
  }
}
```

Comment: Just ran your code example in browser: it does list `getFullList` as a function. Why shouldn't it? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The snippet in your question does print the method.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I guess you're expecting the function to actually be called.

To do so, you'd need to check the type of list[key] and actually call the function

```js
const list = {
    firstElement: "Element 1",
    secondElement: "Element 2",
    thirdElement: "Element 3",
    getFullList: function() {
      return this.firstElement + ', ' + this.secondElement + ', ' + this.thirdElement;
    }
};

for (const key in list) {
    if (list.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const value = list[key];
        console.log(key + " " + value);
        if (typeof value === "function") {
            value();
        }
    }
}
```

The console output when logging the function as the value of "getFullList" will be something like

```js
ƒ () {
      return this.firstElement + ', ' + this.secondElement + ', ' + this.thirdElement;
    }
```